# jquery how to do callback function for text editor

Tags: jquery, function, callback

I have 2 pages: **page 1** is a normal page and page 2 is a partialview (**partial 2**). I go to **page 1** and a few seconds later **partial 2** is loaded and shown at the bottom of **page 1**, my problem is that I need to know how to do a callback function in order to get my text editor to bind to the **partial 2** textbox that is loaded after the document is complete for example this is the setup for page 1

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {



            $('#partial2').trigger('submit') ;
        });
</script>
```

As you can see the ckeditor file is what turns any textbox into a text-editor and partial2 is automatically loaded after document is ready but by that time it is too late and I get a regular textbox instead of a text editor how can I do a callback function to fix that..

This is the textbox in my partial2

```
<input type="text" id="post" class="ckeditor" />
```

I know that everything works because if I put that same textbox on page1 I get the text editor; any help would be great . I have tried doing this on **page1** but it did not work

```
         $('#partial2').trigger('submit', function ()
            {
                $("#post").addClass(".ckeditor").ajaxComplete();
            })

            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**CKeditor** initializes all the text inputs it can find when you first load it.
But then, your new content arrives after the page is loaded, and hence the editor does not find them.

Try this (once the new content is loaded):

```
$('#partial2 .ckeditor').ckeditor();
```

More info here: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-for-jQuery